# windows equivalent of this shell script

Tags: shell, batch-file

i'm looking for an equivalent in windows for this shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f  D:/Users/u159615/Desktop/fic ];then
echo 1 > fic
fi
read value < fic

#Rscript myRscript.R $value

value=`expr $value + 1`

echo $value > fic
```

I tried this code :

```
@ECHO OFF 

IF NOT EXIST D:\Users\u159615\Desktop\fic (echo 1 >= fic)

set /p cpt =< fic

rem Rscript myRscript.R %cpt%

set /a cpt = %cpt%+1
echo %cpt% > fic
```

but i have a problem for the windows script, i run the script three times, then i delete the file fic and run it again but the value in the variable cpt is not reset to 1.
does anybody have an idea ?

thanks in advance

Comment: try like this `IF NOT EXIST D:\Users\u159615\Desktop\fic ((echo 1)> fic)`

Comment: and in the last line `(echo %ctp%)>fic`

Comment: I tried but still does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with spaces around `=`. In batch the space will become part of the variable name.`echo digit>file` will be taken as redirection of a stream so in this case you'll need pair of additional brackets.

```
@ECHO OFF 

IF NOT EXIST "D:\Users\u159615\Desktop\fic" ((echo 1)>fic)

set /p cpt=<fic

rem Rscript myRscript.R %cpt%

set /a cpt=%cpt%+1
(echo %cpt%)>fic
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with npocmaka, but I don't like mixing up absolute and relative pathes.

```
@ECHO Off
Set fic="%UserProfile%\Desktop\fic"
IF NOT EXIST %fic% (>%fic% echo 1)
set /p "cpt="<%fic%

rem Rscript myRscript.R %cpt%

set /a "cpt+=1"
Echo new cpt=%cpt%
>%fic% echo %cpt%
```